# list view setOnItemClickListener do nothing in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

setOnItemClickListener event doesn't work in Fragment.my setOnItemClickListener is in onPostExecute ...please help me out guys....thnx in advance.here is my code

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
ListView lvHome;


public HomeFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    lvHome = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvHome);

    //Start download
    new JSONTask().execute("http://www.darkabc.com/mobile_home.php");
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);


    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageOneWelcome.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageTwoWelcome.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ImageThreeWelcome.class.getName()));

    mPagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);

    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


    return view;


}
private class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String, List<Bardata>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Bardata> doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader= null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer();

            String line="";
            while ((line =reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("home");

            List<Bardata> bardataList =new ArrayList<>();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for (int i= 0;i<parentArray.length();i++) {


                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Bardata bardata = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), Bardata.class);

                bardataList.add(bardata);

            }
            return bardataList;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<Bardata> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null) {
            HomeAdapter adapter =new HomeAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.homefragmentrow, result);
            lvHome.setAdapter(adapter);
            lvHome.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Bardata bardata = result.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Individualbar.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bardata", new Gson().toJson(bardata));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Not able to fetch data from server, please check your internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
public class HomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<Bardata> barDataList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater ;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Bardata> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        barDataList = objects;
        this.resource =resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.date1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.image11 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            holder.image21 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
            holder.image31 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image3);
            holder.image41 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image4);
            holder.image51 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image5);
            holder.zen1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zen);
            holder.cityname1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityname);
            holder.rating1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(barDataList.get(position).getBar_image(), holder.date1, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        holder.zen1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getBarname());
        holder.cityname1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.rating1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getRating());
        holder.text1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getAboutbar());




        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{

        ImageView date1;
        ImageView image11;
        ImageView image21;
        ImageView image31;
        ImageView image41;
        ImageView image51;
        TextView zen1;
        TextView cityname1;
        TextView rating1;
        TextView text1;


    }
}
```

}

fragment_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.abhijeetsingh.drawer.HomeFragment">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager2">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/lvHome">
</ListView>
```

homefragmentrow.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/relative1"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tgif"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/line"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TGIF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/zen"
            android:textColor="#EF9C1A"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cityname"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zen"
            android:text="| B-25, Safdarjung, New Delhi"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Rated"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/ratingimage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rated"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ratingimage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="It is a long established fact../>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the click event on item click or whole list click? because I can see you added the click listener to the `ListView` not the list item

Comment: I guess what satnam put in his answer is good, as the listener is added even before the response is received, making it easier to test the response; but you'll have to handle if the response is yet received or not.
One more thing, it's recommended to add an interface function to the fragment and call it in the click and add the intent transition in the calling activity by implementing that interface in the activity

Comment: make sure your `result` is not `null`

Comment: my result is not null...i can see all the data coming for server

Comment: @Abdul-RahmanAhmad bro if i want to send city name and some more string value to server...where i should pass that...

Comment: Check the answer I wrote, I couldn't write here in comment, so I made an answer to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

You have Made the FrameLayout Clickable which is stealing the clickEvent and Kistview is unable to call OnItemClick Method.

> android:clickable="true"

Remove above line from FrameLayout.
It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Do onItemClick outside where you defined AsyncTask.

Comment: bro if i want to send city name and some more string value to server...where i should pass that...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class HomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<Bardata> barDataList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater ;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Bardata> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        barDataList = objects;
        this.resource =resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.date1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.image11 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            holder.image21 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
            holder.image31 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image3);
            holder.image41 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image4);
            holder.image51 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image5);
            holder.zen1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.zen);
            holder.cityname1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cityname);
            holder.rating1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Bardata data = barDataList.get(position);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new Listener(data))
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(data.getBar_image(), holder.date1, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        holder.zen1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getBarname());
        holder.cityname1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.rating1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getRating());
        holder.text1.setText(barDataList.get(position).getAboutbar());




        return convertView;
    }

     class Listener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private Bardata data;

        Listener(Bardata data) {
            this.data = data;

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),   Individualbar.class);
                intent.putExtra("bardata", new Gson().toJson(data));
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder{

        ImageView date1;
        ImageView image11;
        ImageView image21;
        ImageView image31;
        ImageView image41;
        ImageView image51;
        TextView zen1;
        TextView cityname1;
        TextView rating1;
        TextView text1;


    }
}
```

Comment: you need to set listener on each and every view in adapter try this

Comment: bro if i want to send city name and some more string value to server...where i should pass that...

Comment: and thnks for the last question...i did like u said...and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this outside the AsyncTask.

```
    lvHome.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Bardata bardata = result.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),   Individualbar.class);
                intent.putExtra("bardata", new Gson().toJson(bardata));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Not able to fetch data from server, please check your internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: but i want to send the result with intent...if i put it outside it show error with my result..

Comment: then how i can get the result there...can u please tell that??

Comment: Use a global variable

Comment: global variable is a very bad idea, i think.
User interface for communication: check these links [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) & [Here](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

Comment: create one global string and put the value of result. and that use outside it.

Comment: bro if i want to send city name and some more string value to server...where i should pass that...

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for an additional question asked in the comments:

If you're doing a `GET` call, add the parameter to the URL like `/get_call?parameter_1=value_1&parameter_2=value_2`. If it's a `POST` or `PUT`, you can use `OutputStreamWriter` with `BufferedWriter` to put your parameters to url.

Example:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
BufferedWriter bw = null;
if (out != null) {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
} else {
    // Connection Error
}
try {
    bw.write(parametersAsString);
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can use a `JSONObject` to put parameters and values, and put them in `parametersAsString` replacement by using `toString()` function

Comment: i want to send city name and get values according to that city name...from url,...

Comment: You can put the city name in the parameters, but the result cannot be retrieved from the url, but rather in the `onPostExecute` function. You have a list as result, so you can do the comparison needed in a loop by assigning city name as a class variable of the Fragment class, which will be accessible in the `PostExecute`